# Why cant i cast an Action<Int32> to Action<Object>?

Tags: c#, casting

I have several places where i have `Action<Int32>`, `Action<Boolean>`, `Action<SomeClassName>` being used, but when it comes to passing the action as an argument in a class method, i cannot cast `Action<Int32>` or `Action<Boolean>` to `Action<Object>`.

Why can a cast not be done with a simple type cast? Is this cast possible at all? And lastly, how would i go about this cast if it is possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it would break type safety.

When you declare `Action<Int32>`, you say "this is a delegate that requires one Int32 parameter".

If this could be directly cast to `Action<object>`, then you are now able to call the action with something that is definitely not `Int32`, for instance a `DateTime`. In this case, C# prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a direct cast via covariance (or is it contravariance?) because an `Action<int>` is fundamentally *not* an `Action<object>` - the latter can be passed *any* object, whereas the former can *only* be passed an `int`.

You *can* work around this by wrapping your action, something like:

```
Action<int> aInt = ...;
Action<object> aObj = o => aInt((int)o);
```

This again shows you why the cast might not be a good idea - if you pass `aObj` anything except an `int`, you'll get a cast exception.

Conversely, you *can* in theory just cast an `Action<object>` to an `Action<int>`, because if you can pass it *any object*, you can *certainly* pass it an `int`. However, in practice this only works for reference types, not value types - so you could do it with `string`, but not with `int`.

Comment: It would be covariance, but `Action<T>` is contravariant in T. It's covariance if the "arrow of convertibility" goes in the same direction.  if `string --> object` implies that `X<string> --> X<object>` then `X<T>` is covariant because the arrows correspond to each other. If `string --> object` implies that `X<string> <-- X<object>` then the arrow is in the contrary direction, so it is contravariant.

Comment: ... and just like that, `co` and `contra` now make sense to me. Thanks Eric!

Answer (score 1):

Action labors under the restriction that its input is an Int32. This means that the action you use can make assumptions about the input being an int. Eg you can do math with another int `n => Console.WriteLine(n + 4)`. So that action, or function, fits nicely in that box. If you change the box, the assumptions made earlier still have to hold. You basically have a reverse relationship, or **contravariance**, to the "regular" casting scenario, eg: `object a = (object) 2;`.

Just remember that anything that fits in the Action box has to make no assumptions about the behaviour of its input. The function `n => Console.WriteLine(n)` fits snugly inside, because all objects can be printed. Not all objects can act like ints.